# Why does post-increment fail in .Aggregate(...) but pre-increment succeeds?

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate, reduce

I was fiddling with one of my project euler answers to try and make it a bit shorter/cleaner/succinct.

I came up with this:

```
Sequences.FibonacciBig() // infinite fib sequence of type BigInteger
    .TakeWhile(f => f.ToString().Length < 1000)
    .Aggregate(1, (i, _) => i++);
```

My test failed as the actual was 1, which seemed odd. I first thought that the lazy enumerable wasn't being evaluated or something like that. I replaced with i += 1 and it worked, test passed. Then I replaced with ++i and it still worked.

I'm confused as to why the statement seems to not be evaluated at all when using the post-increment operator. At worst, I expected some kind of off-by-one error, but not have the aggregate function effectively do nothing.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Post increment returns the value **before** incrementing. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at following code:

```
private int value = 0;

public int GetValue()
{
    return value++;
}
```

would you expect it to return `1` when called for the first time? It doesn't. It returns current value of `value` and than increments it. The same happens to your lambda expression.

```
.Aggregate(1, (i, _) => i++);
```

It returns current value of `i`, and than increments it (which is pointless at that point as you're not holding reference to it anywhere else).

pre-increment and `+=` work because they increment the value before returning it.

Answer (score 2):

`i++` increments `i` as a side effect, but the *value* of the `i++` expression will be the value *before* `i` was incremented, unlike with `++i` where the value will be the value of `i` *after* the increment.

In other words:

```
var i = 3;
var a = i++;
Console.WriteLine("a = {0}, i = {1}", a, i); // a = 3, i = 4
```

Compare this to:

```
var i = 3;
var a = ++i;
Console.WriteLine("a = {0}, i = {1}", a, i); // a = 4, i = 4
```

But anyway this doesn't really matter here since **you shouldn't be incrementing `i` anyway** in your code. You could just write:

```
.Aggregate(1, (i, _) => i + 1)
```

because `i` is a parameter, so it's just a *local variable* that you don't reuse later.

But, actually, why don't you just write `.Count() + 1` instead? Because that's exactly what your `Aggregate` call does...